# Rails: turn off caching for database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I have a drop down menu where its contents is from the database table `types`.

But every time I insert a new entry into the `types` table, the drop down menu is not updated, I suspect the database caching is turned on that prevents this from updating.

Is there a way to turn off the caching so that it can reflect the changes in the database immediately?

thank you.

Comment: There is no database cache, per se (unless you were using a cache store - but then you would know the answer to your question). But Rails does have [other types of caching](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html) that you can disable.  In all likelihood, however, this is not the problem.  Can you post some code that shows how the menu is populated and how the table contents are updated?

Answer (score 0):

you can always use the method `.reload` to assure that you are using the last version of your object (up to the call of `.reload`, of course)